# Add Obj-C module to MonoTouch App

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-controls, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm looking to create a iOS app utilizing SIP functionality for various functions.  I've found the Siphon project hosted here: http://code.google.com/p/siphon/, and see that it's dependent on pjSip.

It looks like I could either create bindings for the pjSip library by following details here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linking_native_libraries or I could potentially create bindings directly into Siphon obj-c library as detailed here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_new_objective-c_types

Would it be possible to create the equivalent of a 'user control' in obj-c representing the dialer pad, controllers, views, logic - and then add that to a MT project, and have that obj-c 'user control' added to a form in MT?

I'm new to obj-c and MT, so please let me know if I missed something obvious, it looks like a lot of this has changed with recent releases.

Update -

After some further research, it looks like it should be possible to have a static library developed within Xcode/Obj-c.  Then added as native reference to a MonoTouch along with bindings and any additional bundles.  Then I should be able call the library method, which retrieves a xib/controller and pushes to display.  I'm imagining this to work similar to Asp.Net MVC Areas?  Can anyone confirm this approach would or would not work?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is absolutely possible.  I've created sample project within MT that adds reference to [Tabku](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) library  and places a TKCalendarMonthlyView onto a form.  This then uses included controller/delegate and bundle resources for interaction.

I used this library because bindings existed for it, there is a nice collection to be found [here](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings).

In addition, you can find project templates for creating a static linked framework [here](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework).

With the above information I was able to create a .a target and define bindings to build a .dll that I could add as reference within MT.  Then I added the required bundle (add folder) assets, defined a new view for display - and we're golden!

Hope this helps anyone in the future

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a new method for linking OBJ-C code in 5.0.1 Monotouch which is a lot easier to use: [Link with Attribute](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types/Binding_Types_Reference_Guide#LinkWithAttribute). Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this looks to be a good solution for passing compiler args and making the process simpler for consumers - I'm still a bit concerned if I can package controller/ui elements within the referenced lib and pass application control to that referenced UI?  

Thanks for the link though, it's good information to have!